# What should I do after finishing the opening campaign?

Tags: galaxy-of-fire

I was really enjoying Galaxy of Fire on the iPhone, but once I finished the opening campaign and did a few of the open-ended missions, it got really repetitive. Is there something else I'm missing?

And are there any other Terran ships after the Wraith for example?

I know it's only an iPhone game and I shouldn't be expecting the world, and I've loved being fondly reminded of Elite, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't more gold to mine before moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off there is [Galaxy of Fire 2](http://toucharcade.com/2010/04/14/a-look-at-upcoming-galaxy-on-fire-2-for-iphone-and-ipad/) to look forward to.

[Here is a complete list of all of the weapons and shields in order from worst to best](http://forums.fishlabs.net/fishlabs-mobile-games-en-20/iphone-ipad-games-55/galaxy-fire-iphone-64/903-galaxy-fire-weapon-ships-guide-2.html). As the list points out, there are ten possible ships. I do not know what ships other than the Wraith you have, but it you don't have ten, then you don't have them all :P

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!